# Should you associate unit tests with Test Plans in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, xunit

I'm currently running xUnit unit tests in by build pipeline to prevent releasing builds with failing tests. I see that there's an option to associated automated tests with test plans within Azure DevOps. Is this a good practice for unit tests, or should this only be done with functional and/or integration tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run unit, function and integration test suites in Azure Pipelines. Azure Test plans is supposed to [improve overall code quality by using manual and exploratory testing services for your applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/?view=azure-devops).